# How to only iterate over one argument of an matrix array if both have the same variable in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to eliminate some non zero entries in a matrix where the 2 adjacent diagonals to the main diagonal are nonzero.

```js
  
h = np.zeros((n**2,n**2))
for i in np.arange(0, n**2):
    for j in np.arange(0,n**2):
        if(i==j):
            for i in np.arange(0,n**2,n):
                h[i,j-1] = 0 
        
print(h)
```

I want it to only eliminate the lower triangle non-zero entries, but it's erasing some entries in the upper triangle. I know this is because on the last if statement with the for loop, it is iterating for both arguments of the array, when I only want it to iterate for the first argument i, but since I set i=j, it runs for both.

The matrix I want to obtain is the following:

[Desired matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvMRb.jpg)

PS: sorry for the extremely bad question format, this is my first question.

Comment: Could you include an expected and actual output?

Comment: @burntchowmein I added the expected matrix.

Comment: You have two nested for loop with same iterator variable `i`. That is usually not recommended as the inner for loop changes the value of `i` while outer for loop also uses same variable. Is that something you intended to do?

Comment: Also I am not sure how you get the desired output. Some of the values in the diagonal on the lower triangle are 0 and some are 1. Could you please elaborate how you set them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
hamiltonian = np.zeros((n**2,n**2))   # store the Hamiltonian
for i in np.arange(0, n**2):
    for j in np.arange(0,n**2):
        if abs(i-j) == 1:
            hamiltonian[i,j] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
hamiltonian[0,1] = 1
hamiltonian[n**2-1,n**2-2] = 1
for i in np.arange(1, n**2-1):
  hamiltonian[i,i+1] = 1
  hamiltonian[i,i-1] = 1
```